# opensips BYE issue - going to local IP

Tags: opensips

Weired problem here. I can see the BYE is not being sent to the actual IP. i see the BYE goes from opensips (1.11.3 tls) to local ip 192.168.1.x 
So call does not hangup.  Everything else works fine.

Thats how i manage the NATED devices.

```
    if (nat_uac_test("18")) {
            if (is_method("REGISTER")) {
                fix_nated_contact(); # Rewrite contact with source IP of signalling
                fix_nated_register();
                force_rport();
                setbflag(6);    # Mark as NATed
            };
                if (is_method("INVITE")) {
                    fix_nated_sdp("10"); # Add direction=active to SDP
                    force_rport();
                };

    };
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code for the resolution of the issue that you are facing.

```
if (is_method("CANCEL|BYE")) {
        if (t_check_trans())
            t_relay();
        exit;
    }
```